# how to fix this query

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

The below method always return an empty array as the query return to data from MySQL.

- It's working if I write the query just like that `SELECT * FROM menu`
- This issue appears on AWS EC2 server and the same method working normally on my localhost
- This `SELECT * FROM menu WHERE type = ? ORDER BY likes DESC` query was working fine before updating the table by adding the location column, now no one working
- I tried to recreate the table from the beginning

  ```
  function getMenu($type)
  {
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE type = ? ORDER BY likes DESC");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $type);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($id, $dish_name, $dish_disc, $type, $image, $location, $likes, $price);
  }
  function getMenuByLocation($type, $location){
      $common = 'common';
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE type = ? AND 
         location IN (?, 'common') ORDER BY likes DESC");
      $stmt->bind_result($id, $dish_name, $dish_disc, $type, $image, 
           $location, $likes, $price);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
          $temp = array();

          $temp['dId'] = $id;
          $temp['dishName'] = $dish_name;
          $temp['dishDisc'] = $dish_disc;
          $temp['type'] = $type;
          $temp['imageUrl'] = $image;
          $temp['location'] = $location;
          $temp['likes'] = $likes;
          $temp['price'] = $price;

          array_push($dish, $temp);
      }
      return $dish;
  }
  ```

Comment: Why using single quote around the names inside your query ? ("SELECT * FROM `menu` WHERE `type` = ? ORDER BY `likes` DESC;" - and why using ';' at the end ?

Comment: Already done and nothing changed

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: No, only empty result

Comment: Can you edit the question with your updated code ?

Comment: Updated as required

Comment: Do you get results when using your query without location ? and one more question, why write your query like this ? IN (?, 'common')

Comment: Firstly no, no result (empty),
I need you to know that this query is working from my localhost

Comment: Is your mysql connection data and table name correct ? That could happen often to make mistake when working on two different environment !

Comment: Correct copy and paste

Comment: That's the point, you shouldn't copy and paste ! Check the other answer in this post, make sure you use correct data for your connection.

Comment: Thank you,  I am talking about the tables names and data

Comment: Well, Your query look fine on my eyes, I cannot imagine something else except wrong connection data, or if you have any log data to share :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about user privileges on table 'menu'. Check user rights

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'domain';
```

changing 'user'@'domain' to your user name in connection string.

Try

```
GRANT ALL ON your_db_name.menu TO 'user'@'domain';
```

Note that this query should be executed by a user with enough privileges.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html as needed.